# Update non 0 records based on the subsequent non 0 records in another column

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>  ID      Index1    Index2
> 0001       0         0
> 0001       0         0
> 0001       2         0
> 0001       0         3
> 0002       0         0
> 0002       2         0
> 0002       0         4
> ```

Is there a way to update the values different from 0 in column Index1 based on Index2?
In other words if the subsequent value in Index2 is >=2 then the previous (not 0) in Index1 column must be 1.

Desired output:

> ```
>  ID      Index1    Index2
> 0001       0         0
> 0001       0         0
> 0001       1         0
> 0001       0         3
> 0002       0         0
> 0002       1         0
> 0002       0         4
> ```

Comment: Can you reverse the order of the observations?  It is much easier to look back than to predict the future.

Answer (score 2):

SAS doesn't support leads *directly*, but you can do it a number of ways. Here's an easy method that merges the data onto itself using a 1-1 merge, but increments the second table by a single observation in order to get a "lead".

```
data want;
    merge have
          have(firstobs=2 
               keep=id index2 
               rename=(id = lead_id 
                       index2 = lead_index2 
                      ) 
              )
    ;

    if(lead_index2 > 0 AND index1 > 0 AND id = lead_id) then index1 = 1;

    drop lead_index2;
run;
```

By setting `firstobs=2`, we're telling SAS to merge these two tables:

```
      Table 1            Table 2
------------------ | --------------------
ID  Index1  Index2 | lead_id  lead_Index2           
1   0       0      | 1        0
1   0       0      | 1        0
1   2       0      | 1        3  
1   0       3      | 2        0
2   0       0      | 2        0
2   2       0      | 2        4
2   0       4      |
```

Since it's trying to do a 1-1 merge, the last observation will be missing since there's no match between the last observation of table 1 and table 2. This makes our logic really easy to compare: if `lead_Index2` is > 0, `Index1` is > 0, and the IDs match then set `index1` to 1.

Comment: I should also note that this only works in your specific case. If you run into a situation where it's the last ID in a group, the next ID has `index2 > 0` and the current ID's `index1 > 0`,  you'll hit a problem. I changed the code to account for this.

Comment: Which is why I prefer to use a second SET statement instead of MERGE.  Then you can use BY statement with the main SET statement to enable BY group processing.

Comment: I had tried that initially but was running into some issues getting it to work. I'm just okay with double-set statements. Can you post a solution that includes it as an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if the observations were ordered in the opposite order. It is easier to remember something than to predict the future. In SAS you can remember things with a retained variable or the LAG() function.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  lag_index2 = lag(index2);
  if first.id then call missing(lag_index2);
  index1= (lag_index2 > 1) ;
run;
```

If you really need to look ahead you can read the data twice. The second time start from the second observation. To make the number of observations match include an empty observation at the end.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  set have(firstobs=2 keep=index2 rename=(index2=lead_index2))
      have(obs=1 drop=_all_)
  ;
  if last.id then call missing(lead_index2);
  index1= (lead_index2 > 1) ;
run;
```